# partitioning problems

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ubuntu-11.04

I had on my laptop a dual system (Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows 7) and someway the partitions messed-up. Windows stopped from booting, I just got a blinking cursor, but Ubuntu worked fine. I tried to fix the windows boot (fixmbr, fixboot, bootsect /nt60 C:/....) but now grub was overwritten and I have no OS. Finally I formatted the hdd (low format), installed Windows, partition hdd with paragon partition manager and now I want to install Ubuntu, but Ubuntu sees an empty hdd, weird, can anyone tell me what can I do?

[image: Ubuntu gparted]

[image: Windows Disk Management]

EDIT:

I have created:

partition 1: 100MB ntfs - windows reserved (drive B)

partition 2: 50GB ntfs win 7  (drive C)

partition 3: 50GB ext3 linux

partition 4: 'the rest' ntfs for data  (drive E)

(the swap i will create after)

Comment: first i created a partition, installed windows, then tried to install ubuntu, but it saw an empty hdd, so i tried paragon, created the partitions for linux, but still ubuntu detected a empty hdd (this is not the first time i install OS's or create partitions)

Comment: Drive B? Does it really show up as B?

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot :)

Comment: Curious, did you ever answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=282018), `The logical partition within the extended partition would be sda5.` Even if the partition didn't show up, I guess you could manually specify the partition as sda5 and see if that works.

[This](http://www.poopoccurs.com/howto/logical.html) page might offer some help as well, but I am not sure. I hope either one of them can give you some advice in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave up and reformatted and repartitioned the HDD. It works fine. I have no idea what happened..

I would have liked to have more time to study the problem...